# Smarty3 block append in included template

Tags: include, smarty, block, smarty3

I have some templates written with Smarty 3:

1. A layout page
2. An index page
3. An include page

layout.tpl:

```
{block "css"}{/block}
{block "js"}{/block}
{block "content"}{/block}
```

index.tpl:

```
{extends "layout.tpl"}
{block "content"}
content text
{include "include.tpl"}
{/block}
```

include.tpl

```
{block "js" append}
include some extra js files for this included content
{/block}
include text
```

But I got a compiler exception:

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template include.tpl {block "js" prepend} too many shorthand attributes

Is block append not available in an included template, even if it's included by the child template?

I think it'll be very helpful if I can use block append some way like this, or there might be other ways to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Smarty's template inheritance is processed before the parser even knows about your {include}. Thus it cannot handle {block}s in included templates. That is, unless the included template doesn't extend another template itself.

Answer (score 0):

"too many shorthand attributes" is referring to the lack of attribute names in the statement:

```
{block "js" append}
```

Smarty gets confused because it is no longer clear what each attribute is referring to.

Instead, replace the shorthand attribute for "js" with the longhand version name="js" and you should be fine:

```
{block name="js" append}
```